# How do I import a csv file with phpmyadmin containing 1 column into my mysql database?

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I added a new column on my existing database table.

I have saved all the data I want to add an Excel table, under a new column called "path" and have saved it as .csv

My existing table has 12 columns and 5000 rows.

I have tried many different attempts as using the Import option but none work.  I get no error messages, but no data is added.

Attempt #1:
I saved only 2 columns of data:
id,path

(The "id" is a unique auto-incrementing number identifier)

Attempt #2:
I saved only 1 column of data:
path

Attempts #3 and #4 were using the above attempts, but removing the row with column names from the .csv
This still did not work.

phpMyAdmin used to have an Import option checkbox for "The first line of the file contains the table column names (if this is unchecked the first line will become part of the data).  However, this no longer appears as an option.

Nothing I am doing is working... please tell me how to make this work.

Comment: You should add what technologies you are using, such as Database brand, import tool, programming language, etc...

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that. I was directed here from phpmyadmin website.  I wanted to post this on a phpmyadmin user forum, but their site sent me here, I assume I was posting this under some thread or area for phpmyadmin questions.  After much trial and error, I was finally able to accomplish what I wanted -- no thanks to the lack of documentation about import instructions. There's also lots of YouTube videos on importing an entire table, but none that I could find on just importing specific columns.Is there any way that I can show this post as being "resolved" or should I just delete it?

Comment: I think that you may be able to answer your own question. Try to post a reply explaining how you solved. That may help others who have the same issue. Though not sure if you need to gain more reputation to reply questions; in that case just add another comment explaining your solution.

Comment: Thanks, I have done that now.  I have never used stackoverflow before and am not fully familiar with the environment here.

Answer (score 0):

I did figure this out with a little bit of trial and error.

To do this I had to:

1. Saved my info in 2 columns: The first was my "id" number column, and the second was the "path" name column.  (Note: phpMyAdmin no longer appears to prompt you if your .csv data has a header row, so make sure you do not have a header (column name) row in your .csv file.
2. In phpMyAdmin, Target the table you want to import the data into, and select the "Import" tab, and then select your .csv file you want to import.
3. Check the checkbox for "Update data when duplicate keys found on import (add ON DUPLICATE UPDATE)".  (This was the main thing that caused me issues because I was not checking it -- I was misreading as doing something else).
4. In the "Column names" field, type in the names of the columns you are wanting to update (one of which needs to be your primary key column).  In my case I had to type: id,path

That was what did the trick for me.

Comment: I am using PHP 7.0.33 and the 'Import' facility for CSV files has "Skip this number of queries (for SQL) starting from the first one." This allows you to import WITH a header in your file -> simply set this to '1' and your header is ignored.